# Microsoft Graph MIME content

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, mime, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to get MIME content from mail via Microsoft Graph.
It works fine for the emails received. But for sent mail, the MIME file is missing **sentDateTime**

"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('9c934d23-5f49-4bdc-b1cc-8e5822d479bb')/messages/$entity",

```
"@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACBmUMmRgniS66W2x3+/Z4uAANecm6i\"",

"id": "AAMkADJjNThkZDIzLTM0M2MtNDBkNS1iNmNlLWEzMWEzYjMwY2M2NgBGAAAAAADQJQpK-gaHR5h_hbt1-C17BwCBmUMmRgniS66W2x3_-Z4uAAJUh6HiAACBmUMmRgniS66W2x3_-Z4uAANJ-s5hAAA=",

"createdDateTime": "2020-11-28T13:32:33Z",

"lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-11-28T13:33:17Z",

"changeKey": "CQAAABYAAACBmUMmRgniS66W2x3+/Z4uAANecm6i",
"categories": [
    "NIRAS copy to: Passed"
],
"receivedDateTime": "2020-11-28T13:31:00Z",
"**sentDateTime**": "2020-11-28T13:31:45Z",
"hasAttachments": false,
```

***MIME content: ...../messages/AAMkADJjNT...***

From: "Reza Matin (REMA)" XXXX@niras.dk

To: Reza Matin yyyyy@gmail.com

Subject: MIME send mail test

Thread-Topic: MIME send mail test

Thread-Index: AdbFitC4fR/JJs5vSaCOp5gLqDx+jA==

Date: Sat,

28 Nov 2020 13: 31: 45 +0000

Message-ID:
AM9PR07MB71863080DD521AEA1FAF9C18A7F70@AM9PR07MB7186.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com

Keywords: NIRAS copy to: Passed

Content-Language: da-DK

X-MS-Has-Attach:

X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-RecordReviewCfmType: 0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="*000_AM9PR07MB71863080DD521AEA1FAF9C18A7F70AM9PR07MB7186eurp*"

MIME-Version: 1.0

--*000_AM9PR07MB71863080DD521AEA1FAF9C18A7F70AM9PR07MB7186eurp*

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

Comment: Do you see the issue only for this email or for any email stored in sent items folder?

Comment: Only for mails stored in sent items folder.

Comment: Cool. Let me look at this.